# What's the programmatic way to make a UIImageView pin to it's superview's top, left, right, bottom, equal width, and equal height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to understand how auto layout works programmatically. I know we can assign it in the Interface Builder but I want to learn more about how it works underneath.

If someone could show me the code to make a UIImageView pin it's top, left, right, and bottom alignments (as well as equal width and equal height) that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

```
yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(yourView);

[superview addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[yourView]|"
  options:(NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing)
  metrics:nil
  views:views]];

[superview addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[yourView]|"
  options:(NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom)
  metrics:nil
  views:views]];`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the constraints using native NSLayoutConstraints as follows:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[superview addSubview:view1];

UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[superview addConstraints:@[

    //view1 constraints
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:padding.top],

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:padding.left],

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:-padding.bottom],

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:-padding.right],

 ]];
```

This would be very complex for the beginners, one easy way to achieve this with few lines of code is to use autolayout wrappers like **Masonry**.

With Masonry, you can do the same as above :

Heres the same constraints created using `MASConstraintMaker`

```
UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top); //with is an optional semantic filler
    make.left.equalTo(superview.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
    make.bottom.equalTo(superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(-padding.bottom);
    make.right.equalTo(superview.mas_right).with.offset(-padding.right);
}];
```

Or even shorter

```
[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(superview).with.insets(padding);
}];
```